# PyTorch Lightning training stalling at the beginning of fourth batch

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, dataloader

I am having an odd problem in PyTorch Lightning, which I'm using for finetuning a language model on a GPU.  The first three training batches run very quickly (<1 second), then the fourth goes on for hours without finishing, and eventually I cancel the job.  This is true whether I use batches of size 2 or 16.

Using the callbacks `on_train_batch_start` and `on_train_batch_end` to print `'batch started'` and `'batch ended'`, I know that the first three batches have all completed, and the fourth doesn't reach the `on_train_batch_start` callback.  This leads me to believe that the problem is somewhere in the `DataLoader`, since `on_train_batch_start` appears to be the first hook in the training loop, according to PyTorch Lightning's pseudocode.

I place some printing statements in my custom `collate_fn` for the `DataLoader`, and they all printed as well, so it appears that the problem arises sometime after collating occurs.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be or how I can interrogate the code further?

Comment: Could you kindly add your code here to avoid confusion and to get a better understanding of the problem ?

Comment: @Harshanand I subclassed the `DataLoader` class so I could time parts, and found that it was at the `next()` line.  In the end, I was able to solve the problem, though I don't understand it.  I had set `num_workers = 1`, which is what a warning message on the computing cluster told me to do when I set it to a higher number.  But when I set it to `0`, that fixed everything.

Normally, I add code to my questions, but I didn't even consider it could just be the DataLoader line of code, and I didn't want to vomit my entire code onto the page.  I should have just included it anyway.